# Combine class selectors with descendant selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to overide some jquery classes but i want to do the override just if those classes appear under ul li a

is it possible combine decendant selectors with classes selectors?
For example  - write something like: ul li a .someClass?
Thanks

Comment: Give us sample HTML and say which element you'd like to select!

Comment: Of cause, it is possible to combine selector, but you have to combine them properly so that it fit's your requirement. The code sniplet is necessary for us to answer.

Comment: @Ofir: Did you mean to paste something into your question? Use the edit button.

Comment: Sorry the is code to long for here. Look at the next link:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12327976/New%20Text%20Document%20(2).txt
I want override the next classes:
.ui-li .ui-btn-inner a.ui-link-inherit, .ui-li-static.ui-li
But just for the last <a> inside the ul li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as `ul li > a.somelcass` which means direct descendant `link tag` inside `ul` and `li` with `class someclass`.